# Itemize list inside a tikzpicture node

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, itemize

I'm trying to put a boxed `itemize` list inside my Ti*k*Z figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (1.7, 10) {\texttt{q1}};
\node at (1.7, 8) {\texttt{q2}};
\draw [-{>[length=3mm,width=3mm]},line width=1pt] (2, 10) -- (5, 10);
\draw [-{>[length=3mm,width=3mm]},line width=1pt] (2, 9) -- (5, 8.8);
\node at (5, 10) {\framebox{\Large
    {\begin{itemize}
        \item \texttt{[0]}
        \item \texttt{[1]}
        \item \texttt{[2]}
    \end{itemize}}
}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I get

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` at the line `}};
```

and I don't understand why (since I have fed `\itemize` three `\item`s.) Can anyone help?

Comment: Try `\vbox` instead of `\framebox`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use a `\parbox`, but since you probably want it to be the natural width of the text I used `varwidth` in the example below:

[image]

but I would recommend you use `\nodes` instead for each of the bulleted items, which makes it easier to connect them.  To draw the box around the nodes you can use the `fit` library:

[image]

You can adjust the value of `inner sep=` to control the spacing between the text and the box.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (1.7, 10) {\texttt{q1}};
\node at (1.7, 8) {\texttt{q2}};
\draw [-{>[length=3mm,width=3mm]},line width=1pt] (2, 10) -- (5, 10);
\draw [-{>[length=3mm,width=3mm]},line width=1pt] (2, 9) -- (5, 8.8);
\node at (5, 10) {\framebox{\Large
    {\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}\begin{itemize}
        \item \texttt{[0]}
        \item \texttt{[1]}
        \item \texttt{[2]}
    \end{itemize}\end{varwidth}}
}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Suggested Solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (Q1) at (1.7, 10) {\texttt{q1}};
    \node (Q2) at (1.7, 8) {\texttt{q2}};

    \node [font=\Large] (top)    at (5,10) {$\bullet$ [0]};
    \node [font=\Large] (middle) at (5,9)  {$\bullet$ [1]};
    \node [font=\Large] (bottom) at (5,8)  {$\bullet$ [2]};
    \node[draw=brown, thick,fit={(top) (middle) (bottom)}, inner sep=10pt]   (box) {};

    \draw [-{>[length=3mm,width=3mm]}, red, line width=1pt] (Q1) -- (top);
    \draw [-{>[length=3mm,width=3mm]}, blue,line width=1pt] (Q2) -- (middle);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your suggested code is great... but how do I put a border around the bulleted list and ensure the arrows don't stray inside it?

Comment: @xnx: Opps, sorry I missed that in the first version. Have updated to add a box around the nodes.

Comment: How to remove frame here?

Comment: @Y.zeng: For that the node needs a 'draw=none'.  Thus, changing the 'draw=brown' to 'draw=none' should do it.

Comment: But the frame is created by `\framebox`

Comment: @Y.zeng: I don't know about `\framebox`. You could try using the second solution. Otherwise probably best to post a new question. You should reference this one as that is where the problem originated.

Answer (score 9):

Do you want like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (1.7, 10) {\texttt{q1}};
\node at (1.7, 8) {\texttt{q2}};
\draw [-{>[length=3mm,width=3mm]},line width=1pt] (2, 10) -- (5, 10);
\draw [-{>[length=3mm,width=3mm]},line width=1pt] (2, 9) -- (5, 8.8);
\node [draw] at (5, 10) {\vbox {\Large
    {\begin{itemize}
        \item \texttt{[0]}
        \item \texttt{[1]}
        \item \texttt{[2]}
    \end{itemize}}
}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using a `\vbox` totally rips my image apart. On the left side the vbox and on the right side the moved image.