# How to draw diagram in tikz of following image

Tags: tikz-trees

[image]
 I want to draw following image in latex tikz tree in my thesis

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow I do not know even the ABC of tikz.

Comment: To get you started, here is a link on ow to add [Itemize list inside a tikzpicture node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220820/134144)