# What’s wrong in code

Tags: errors, compilation-error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows}
\begin{document}
\textbf{CELL CYCLE AND CELL DIVISION \hspace{5mm}-\hspace{5mm}(i)MITOSIS/MITOTIC}

\setlength{\parindent}{8.42cm}\textbf{(ii)MEIOSIS/MEIOTIC}
\\\\\\

\begin{center}
%styles
\tikzstyle{block1}   =[rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners,minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,fill=green!40]
\tikzstyle{block2}   =[rectangle,draw=red,rounded corners,minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.39cm,fill=yellow!40]
\tikzstyle{block3}   =[rectangle,draw=purple,rounded corners,minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=2cm,]
\tikzstyle{arrow}    =[thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}
%entering
\node[block1](nick1){\textbf{CELL CYCLE-[MITOSIS]}};
\node[block3,above of=nick1,yshift=1cm](int){\textcolor{cyan}{\underline{MITOSIS}} - No. of Chromosones in the parent and progeny cells is same. It is called as equational division};
\node[block2,below of=nick1,xshift=-3cm](nick2){Interphase};
\node[block2,below of=nick1,xshift=3cm](nick3){M-Phase(Mitosis Phase)};
\node[block3,below of=nick2](des1)
{The Interphase is divided into $3$ phases
\begin{itemize}
\item $G_1$-Phase(Gap-$1$)
\item $S$-Phase(Synthesis)
\item $G_2$-Phase(Gap-$2$)
\end{itemize}};
%arrows
\draw[arrow](nick1) -| (nick2);
\draw[arrow](nick1) -|(nick3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  We're going to need a little more to go on.  Why do you think there is something wrong?  Are you able to remove some code and still have the wrong thing happen?  Can you use that process to narrow down what's wrong?

Comment: [Itemize list inside a tikzpicture node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220820/134144) might be worth having a look at.

Comment: "what's wrong here" is not a useful title for future searches.  Please fix the title and then in the question say what output you get and what you expected.  `\\\\\\ ` is of course wrong and will give multiple errors, simply delete that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled the text you provided as MWE and after adding the `varwidth` enviroment it outputs the next result.

[image]

Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\textbf{CELL CYCLE AND CELL DIVISION \hspace{5mm}-\hspace{5mm}(i)MITOSIS/MITOTIC}

\setlength{\parindent}{8.42cm}\textbf{(ii)MEIOSIS/MEIOTIC}
\\\\\\

\begin{center}
%styles
\tikzstyle{block1}   =[rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners,minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,fill=green!40]
\tikzstyle{block2}   =[rectangle,draw=red,rounded corners,minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.39cm,fill=yellow!40]
\tikzstyle{block3}   =[rectangle,draw=purple,rounded corners,minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=3cm,]
\tikzstyle{arrow}    =[thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}
%entering
\node[block1](nick1){\textbf{CELL CYCLE-[MITOSIS]}};
\node[block3,above of=nick1,yshift=1cm](int){\textcolor{cyan}{\underline{MITOSIS}} - No. of Chromosones in the parent and progeny cells is same. It is called as equational division};
\node[block2,below of=nick1,xshift=-3cm](nick2){Interphase};
\node[block2,below of=nick1,xshift=3cm](nick3){M-Phase(Mitosis Phase)};
\node[block3,below of=nick2,yshift=-1cm](des1){\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth} The Interphase is divided into $3$ phases\par\vspace{0.1in}
\begin{itemize}
\item $G_1$-Phase(Gap-$1$)
\item $S$-Phase(Synthesis)
\item $G_2$-Phase(Gap-$2$)
\end{itemize}\end{varwidth}};
%arrows
\draw[arrow](nick1) -| (nick2);
\draw[arrow](nick1) -|(nick3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, don't use obsolete syntax for nodes styles. Instead of `\tikzstyle` is more correct `\tikzset`. For example, `\tikzset{block1/.style  = {rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners,minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,fill=green!40}, ...}`

Comment: I was using the same code Divya Prakash Sinha used in the MWE, fixing it so it compiles and behave as intended. I will see the code you provided.

Comment: Also, your image spill out of text ...

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear, what you like to have. Something like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Since your image is wider than text width, I introduce `geometry` package to define smaller page margins (I use its default settings). Also first text is inserted in tabular. Image is slightly modified that can be fit into text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shadows, shapes}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\bfseries}l c >{\bfseries}l @{}}
CELL CYCLE AND CELL DIVISION
    & - & (i) MITOSIS/MITOTIC   \\
    &   & (ii) MEIOSIS/MEIOTIC
\end{tabular}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 3mm,
block1/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, fill=green!40, 
                 minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, font=\bfseries},
block2/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=red, fill=yellow!40,
                 minimum width=1.5cm, align=center},
block3/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=purple,
                 text width=#1, align=left},
 arrow/.style = {thick,-Stealth}
                        ]
%entering
\node[block3=0.9\linewidth] (int) {\textcolor{cyan}{\underline{MITOSIS}} - No. of Chromosones in the parent and progeny cells is same. It is called as equational division};
\node[block1,below=of int]          (nick1) {CELL CYCLE-MITOSIS};
\node[block2,below  left=of nick1]  (nick2) {Interphase};
\node[block2,below right=of nick1]  (nick3) {M-Phase\\ (Mitosis Phase)};
\node[block3=0.45\linewidth,
                    below=of nick2] (des1)  {The Interphase is divided into 3 phases:
        \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item $G_1$-Phase (Gap-1)
    \item $S$-Phase (Synthesis)
    \item $G_2$-Phase (Gap-2)
        \end{itemize}
};
%arrows
\draw[arrow] (nick1) -| (nick2);
\draw[arrow] (nick1) -| (nick3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```