# itemize in smartdiagrams

Tags: itemize, smartdiagram

How can I add an `itemize` block in one of the bubbles in this example https://texample.net/tikz/examples/smart-bubbles/ using the `smartdiagram`package.

I have tried `\begin{itemize}\item\end{itemize}` but it doesnt work

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage{dtklogos}

\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]
{   
{Binary Classifiers}
,{Bayes Decision Theory,{ \begin{itemize}
    \item {a}
\end{itemize}
}
}
,{Loss Function Optimization}
,{Others}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem.

Comment: This is not different than the problem of having an itemize environment within a TikZ node: see [Itemize list inside a tikzpicture node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220820/13304) and use `varwidth` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bubble  diagram` doesn't support lists. For use it in some bubble, you need to enclose list in `parbox` or `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[ border=10pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
%\usepackage{metalogo}
%\usepackage{dtklogos}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{bubbleitem}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[bubbleitem]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                     label      = $\bullet$ ,
                     after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                     }


\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]
{
{Binary Classifiers}
,{\parbox{3.6cm}{\raggedright
    Bayes Decision Theory
    \begin{bubbleitem}
    \item a
    \item b
    \end{bubbleitem}}}
,{Loss Function Optimization}
,{Others}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]