# Nodes spaced vertically at exactly 1 \baselineskip apart

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, layout

I'm following the idea behind this post

[Itemize list inside a tikzpicture node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220820/itemize-list-inside-a-tikzpicture-node)

I would like to place the nodes at exactly 1 `\baselineskip` of each other such that even when changing font family or other measurements in the document everything will fit accordingly.

What I did was

```
\node [font=\Large] (top)    at (5,$0 + \baselineskip * 1$)  {$\bullet$ [0]};
\node [font=\Large] (middle) at (5,$0 + \baselineskip * 2$)  {$\bullet$ [1]};
\node [font=\Large] (bottom) at (5,$0 + \baselineskip * 3$)  {$\bullet$ [2]};
```

Which basically is the "math/calc mode" of tikz but It doesn't work, as I expected, and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Using calc library also works but it needs to cover the whole coordinate not just part of it, be very careful with the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to use the `calc` library to do that? The way you tried to use it is wrong, btw. A simple solution would be the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \foreach \i in {12,24,36}
        {
        \setlength{\baselineskip}{\i pt}
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [font=\Large] (top)    at (5,1*\baselineskip)  {$\bullet$ [0]};
            \node [font=\Large] (middle) at (5,2*\baselineskip)  {$\bullet$ [1]};
            \node [font=\Large] (bottom) at (5,3*\baselineskip)  {$\bullet$ [2]};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \bigskip
        
        }
\end{document}
```

[image: spacing nodes]

Comment: It simply is much simpler than what I thought initially ...