# itemize in a tikz flowchart environment

Tags: tikz-styles, flow-charts

I am trying to create a flowchart of the following form:

[image]

the MWE is here:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,fit,matrix,shapes,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document} 
\tikzset{
    decision/.style={
        diamond,
        draw,
        text width=4em,
        text badly centered,
        inner sep=0pt
    },
    block/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        minimum width=4cm,
        minimum height=1cm,
%       text width=10em,
        text centered,
        rounded corners
    },
    cloud/.style={
        draw,
        ellipse,
        minimum height=2em
    },
    descr/.style={
        fill=white,
        inner sep=2.5pt
    },
    connector/.style={
        -latex,
        font=\scriptsize
    },
    rectangle connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) },
        pos=0.5
    },
    rectangle connector/.default=-2cm,
    straight connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path=--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    }
}   
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[block](H1){3};
        \node (emptyblock) [below of=H1,node distance=2cm]{};               
        \node[block,left of = emptyblock, node distance=4cm](H2){2};    
        \node[block,below of = H2, node distance=1.5cm](H3){
            \begin{itemize}
                \item A
                \item B
                \item C
        \end{itemize}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I constantly get the error

> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item aA

Comment: @Marijn when I use the posted solution the boxes containing a,b,c are intersecting with 2 and 3. Moreover, the width and height of the box varies with the length of a, b and c

Comment: For a fixed width you can use a parbox instead of varwidth, as mentioned in that answer. See an example at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652972/how-can-i-write-enumerate-inside-a-rectangle-shape?noredirect=1&lq=1. To make them not intersect you can increase the `node distance` or use `below=2cm of H2` and remove the `node distance=1.5cm` completely.